# DNS and port-forwarding

Tags: dns

I have a server behind `NAT`. I did port forwarding on my router `WRT54GL`. On that server I'm also planning on using BIND9 for DNS services.
My question: **Can I use that DNS server for all ports or only www(80)?** 
I mean, I will have my `domain name` forwarded to my routers STATIC IP, router would then forward all the request to DNS server. DNS server would then decide if this is mail, vpn, website.

I'm sorry, I'm not sure how to explain..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be a little confused on what DNS server's do.  DNS servers only resolve DNS requests.   It doesn't make any sense to forward all requests to your DNS server.

Here's what would happen:

1. A user types in www.example.com in their web browser
2. The user's computer sends a request to their DNS server (not yours)
3. The DNS server responds with the static IP address
4. The user's computer sends an HTTP request to port 80 of your router.
5. Your router then needs to forward that to a web server.

No where in this process would your internal DNS server come into play.

What you need to do is setup a port forward for port 80 to your web server's internal IP address.  So if your web server's IP address is 192.168.1.100, setup a port forward on your router so all traffic for port 80 is forwarded to 192.168.1.100.

Traffic types (web, mail, etc.) are usually differentiated by port number not by DNS.

Comment: No DNS is only for IP addresses.  DNS resolves domain names to IP addresses.  DNS doesn't care, nor know anything about HTTP.

Comment: hm, thanks for explanation. but what if i wanted to add network drives to a computer. can i use dns to resolve address to IP?

Comment: @intelis Your DNS Server will handle the "Name" to IP conversion. All network communication are all IP based. The DNS Server made it easier for you to have a name easy for human to remember and automatically convert the name into IP address that the computer can understand. To add network drives on your computer, you can either use your server IP address, or if the DNS server works as it intended, use your server Name, which will automatically resolve the name into IP, and let you add the network drive by name. eg. \\192.168.1.1\share vs \\myServer\share

Comment: For many days I'm looking to learn this point and finally i reached to a related post, port forward looks like a temporary solution, how does web hosting companies implement this when a web request reach to a router how it diverts to related web server?